# All keys to a list, for example VK_A..Z for user to select

Tags: java, swing, list, combobox, keyboard-events

I am making a program that allows user to custom keyboard shortcuts, for this i need the available keys to be displayed, what is the best way to achieve this in java swing?

```
    KeyEvent.class.getDeclaredFields()
```

I am intrested in dynamic example of below,

```
keysLST.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "CTRL", "ALT", "SHIFT" }));
```

one way i know is to get all from the keyevent class but i am not sure how to integrate it to the list. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of picking from a list, add a KeyListener to any component (a JTextField works) and record the key code as the user presses the key. You can also record modifiers (ctrl,alt,shift) this way.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    int keyTheUserJustPressed = e.getKeyCode();

    // then use for ctrl/alt/shift
    e.getModifiersEx();

    // or use
    e.isAltDown();
    e.isShiftDown();
}
```

Comment: Hi basszero ,

i want to keep these choice as they will be used later by a robot, the robot will sending the keys it reads from the list box or from default is none is selected.

Comment: then save the e.getKeyCode() into some structure outside of the listener

Comment: On further investigation i believe your orignal idea was good one, it is easier for the user to click the keys than to go through a huge list. thanks for the help!